# Why is require_once is nulling variable name on last iteration of readdir()?

Tags: php, file, directory

Why is require_once is clearing variable name on last iteration of readdir()?

```
$added = array();
$folder = 'database';
$contents = opendir($folder);

while($filename = readdir($contents)){
    if(! is_dir($filename) ) {//if not dir
        echo '<BR/><BR/>';
        var_dump($filename);
        echo '<BR/>';
        $added[] = $folder.'/'.$filename;
        require_once($folder.'/'.$filename);
        var_dump($filename);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following output:

```
string(8) "init.php" 
string(8) "init.php" 

string(14) "dbContract.php" 
string(14) "dbContract.php" 

string(12) "requires.php" 
NULL
```

instead of:

```
string(8) "init.php" 
string(8) "init.php" 

string(14) "dbContract.php" 
string(14) "dbContract.php" 

string(12) "requires.php" 
string(12) "requires.php"
```

however, i do get the expected output when I comment out the line:

```
require_once($folder.'/'.$filename);
```

Comment: Have you excluded . and .. ?

Comment: perhaps something in `requires.php` is overriding the value of `$filename`

Answer (score 0):

Something in requires.php was changing $filename
thanks @Mark

**Edit**
Think i got it:

```
function requireDir($folder, $subs, &$added){

    $contents = opendir($folder);

    while($filename = readdir($contents)){
        $wholename = $folder.'/'.$filename;

        if(is_dir($wholename)){
            if($filename != '.' && $filename != '..'){
                if($subs){
                    requireDir($wholename,$added);
                }
            }
        }else if(is_file($wholename)){
            $added[] = $wholename;
        }
    }
}
```